# How to accessing a downloaded files on remote client from local machine

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, aws-device-farm, selenium-remotedriver

I have a Selenium Browser config setup which has the following setup:

```
download_path = '/Users/my.user/Downloads'

# Setting capabilities for my browser
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
caps['goog:chromeOptions'] = {
  'prefs' => {
    'download.default_directory' => download_path,
    'download.prompt_for_download' => false,
    'profile.default_content_settings.popups' => 0
  },
  'args' => [
    # 'disable-dev-shm-usage',
    'no-sandbox',
    'disable-popup-blocking',
    'window-size=1400,900',
    'disable-extensions',
    'disable-gpu'
  ]
}
caps['goog:chromeOptions']['prefs']['plugins.always_open_pdf_externally'] = true

# Trying to run this in AWS DeviceFarm
devicefarm = Aws::DeviceFarm::Client.new(region: 'us-west-2', access_key_id: ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                                         secret_access_key: SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
test_grid_url_response = devicefarm.create_test_grid_url(project_arn: ARN, expires_in_seconds: 3000)
remote_url = test_grid_url_response.url

# Setting up a HTTP client to run it in DeviceFarm
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.read_timeout = 5000

# Setting up the browser
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, http_client: client, url: remote_url, capabilities: caps
url = 'https://www.google.com/'
driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
```

I am trying to access a downloaded file on the Windows remote machine from my local machine, but I am unable to.

I have a lambda written for file uploads, which goes like this:

```
driver.file_detector = lambda do |args|
          str = args.first.to_s
          str if File.exist?(str)
        end
```

But I am not able to access any remotely downloaded file from my local machine.

Can anyone suggest any methods to accomplish the same?

I have tried Ruby-based `File.open("C:\\Users\\testnode\\Downloads\\file_name")` which has failed with the following error message:

```
./sample.rb:46:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:\Users\testnode\Downloads\file_name
 (Errno::ENOENT)
        from ./sample.rb:46:in `open'
        from ./sample.rb:46:in `<main>'
```

Comment: `which has failed.` what was the error message? Edit the full error message as text into your question.

Comment: @JeffC Thanks for the input; I have now edited the full error message into the question.

Answer (score 0):

The file that is downloaded is on the remote machine, not locally where the ruby code is running. To access that file you would need use ftp libraries or some other network related programmatic method to reach the machine to read the file.